# Is it possible to unborrow a mutable reference in rust?

Tags: rust

Here is an example

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: Vec<i32>,
    y: i32,
}

let mut p = Point { x: vec![1], y: 7 };

// borrow out mutable reference p to a and b
let Point { x: a, y: b } = &mut p;

// mutate a
a.push(2); 
// how do I get p back?
println!("{:?}", p);
```

Is there a way to unborrow the reference without creating a new block or abstract into function?

Comment: why "without creating a new block"? Creating a block by opening a `{` before the borrow and closing it after the `a.push(2)` is the (pre-NLL) way to signal to Rust where a reference lifetime is expected to end.

Answer (score 10):

Use Rust 2018.

In Rust 2018, which has non-lexical lifetimes (NLL), your example is valid.

Comment: You can enable NLL even when you are not using Rust 2018, by using the nightly compiler and using `#![feature(nll)]`

Comment: @hellow You don't even need to enable NLL on nightly. It's on by default and falls back to the lexical lifetime if NLL fails.

Comment: @TimDiekmann that's not entirely true: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=41a9963fad7d54d9bb60ac40fa3b15e1

Answer (score 6):

You can't. The fields `x` and `y` are (mutably) borrowed, which means `Point` is (mutably) borrowed. All this happens in the same scope, as a result `Point` will remain mutably borrowed until the end of the scope and you can't have a (immutable or mutable) borrow to the data after it is mutably borrowed. [Interior Mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) is what you need to have a look at.

Using `RefCell<T>` :

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: RefCell<Vec<i32>>,
    y: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let p = Point {
        x: RefCell::new(vec![1]),
        y: 7,
    };

    (*p.x.borrow_mut()).push(2);

    println!("{:?}", p);
}
```

**Edit 1:**
Yes, It is possible as per [Yusuke NOJIMA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53512187/5081997). You will need to add the attribute `#![feature(nll)]` to your code , using rust nightly.

```
#![feature(nll)]

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: Vec<i32>,
    y: i32,
}

...
...
```

For more, please refer the [NLL RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2094-nll.md)